# How to access WebAPi after deploying on docker

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

I have my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY  --from=build /build/output .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","TestDockerApi.dll"]
```

I am creating an image using :

```
docker build -t testdocker/api .
```

and then running a container from image using :

```
docker run testdocker/api
```

I can see following message on my console:

> Hosting environment: Production
>   Content root path: /app
>   Now listening on: http://[::]:80
>   Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

I am trying to access using http://localhost/app/TestDockerApi/Values , but it does not work.

Do I need to use docker image IP to access that .

I can see few tutorials suggesting to do this in Entrypoint :

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","TestDockerApi.dll","--server.urls","http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

And then while running the container, mapping the port:

```
docker run -p 80:5000 testdocker/api
```

Is there any way I could access the API with out using portforwarding? I am just trying to get the basics right , why and what should I do.

Comment: I am note sure I fully understand your issue, but have you tried docker run testdocker/api -p 80:80? Or isn't it possible that something is already running on 80 on your host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dockerfile does not manage network configuration outside of the container at all. If you want docker to listen on your host port of 80, you need to bind it when you run your container.

```
docker run -80:80 testdocker/api
```

For more description about mapping and exposing ports, you can read here:
 - https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/docker-networking-rules/

Alternatively you can create your own service composition where you specify these details and specify this in a `docker-compose.yml` file

```
api:
  image: testdocker/api
  ports:
    - "80:80"
```

And then you can simply run with

```
docker-compose up
```

More information is at:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#command-options-overview-and-help

Comment: You're a life saver!